# Virus on vdi files dangerous for host machine?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, virtualbox, malware, virus

I want to use the preinstalled vdi files from virtualboxes.org because it saves me time having it already built for me (what's not to like?).
I don't know if they have viruses on them (they very well might).
I am running a **Windows 8.1** host, and I want to use a linux distribution from this site (specifically Damn Small Linux) So does running these files in VirtualBox pose a threat to my windows 8 system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole idea of Virtualbox, and such technologies, is to create an isolated environment that emulates a seperate computer.  As such, there is no way for a virus in a guest machine to affect the host machine directly, or vice versa, as it acts as a seperate entity.

However, virus propagate via network and disks, so if you connect your host to your guest via any sort of shared folder or network connection there is the risk that any virus will try to contage any connnected system(s).

Comment: Ok so the fact that it is from a site that specifically gives out the vdi file doesn't make it any more dangerous. I accept your answer